# Get Dictionary from another dictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a data type like this

```
Dictionary<string , Dictionary<Key, Value>>
```

I want to extract the `Dictionary<Key, Value>` from this datatype how can I do that

I am working with C#

Comment: have you tried anything? `var inner = outer[key];` perhaps?

Comment: So you want to retrieve a `Dictionary<Key, Value>` by name from the outer dictionary?

Comment: I just want the dictionary

Comment: Say I have Dictionary<string, Dictionary<Key, Value>> variable I want to extract the inner dictionary to another variable so it will be like Dictionary<Key, Value> variable2

Comment: Having a `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<Key, Value>>` doesn't imply that the outer dictionary contains exactly one `Dictionary<Key, Value>`.  The outer dictionary could contain 0, 1, or more inner dictionaries, keyed by `string`.  You can retrieve an inner dictionary if you know the string used to store it: `Dictionary<Key, Value> innerDictionary` = outerDictionary["foo"];`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming:

```
Dictionary<string , Dictionary<Key, Value>> x = ...
```

You can get the inner dictionary like so:

```
Dictionary<Key, Value> innerDictionary = x["outer_key"];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = dict
      .SelectMany(g => g.Select(v => new { Key = g.Key, Value = v }) // This creates an  anonymous type for use further into the query
        //.ToDictionary(
        //    g => g.Key,
        //    g => g.Value);
```